# @CreationTimestamp and @UpdateTimestamp not working with JPA 2.0.2

Tags: java, mysql, spring-data-jpa

Using JPA to interact with MySQL. Code
ImpsLogEntity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "imps_log")
@Getter
@Setter
public class ImpsLogEntity extends ImpsLog {}
```

ImpsLog Class

```
   @Setter
   @Getter
   @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
   @MappedSuperclass
   @ToString
   public class ImpsLog {

      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
      @Column(name = "id")
      private Long id;

      @Column(name = "amount")
      private BigDecimal amount;

      @Column(name = "created_at")
      @CreationTimestamp
      private Date createdAt;

      @Column(name = "updated_at")
      @UpdateTimestamp
      private Date updatedAt;

    }
```

ImpsLogRepo

```
public interface ImpsLogRepo extends JpaRepository<ImpsLogEntity, Long> {
    }
```

ImpsLogBo

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class ImpsLogBo extends ImpsLog {

  private Error error;
}
```

AccountMapper (using mapstruct)

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
@DecoratedWith(AccountMapperDecorator.class)
public interface AccountMapper {

ImpsLogEntity impsLogBoToImpsLogEntity(final ImpsLogBo impsLogBo);
}
```

To create and save the object :

```
ImpsLogBo impsLogBo = new ImpsLogBo() ;
impsLogBo.setAmount(new Bigdecimal(200));
ImpsLogEntity impsLogEntity = 
this.accountMapper.impsLogBoToImpsLogEntity(impsLogBo);
impsLogEntity = this.impsLogRepo.save(impsLogEntity);
```

SQL create statement for imps_log

```
CREATE TABLE `imps_log` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `amount` decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `created_at` (`created_at`),
  KEY `updated_at` (`updated_at`)
)
```

This code gives **org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper -
Column 'created_at' cannot be null** error while saving to DB.

*

> **Strange part, as for other entities this annotation works. And for this entity also, this error is not consistent.**

*